# How to create horizontal grid with 3 items per row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, grid, material-ui

I am rendering bunch of `Player` components using `map()` loop and I would like to display them horizontally side by side using some sort of `Grid` from `material-ui`.

Right now the components are rendering like this:

[image]

And I would like to render them like this:

[image]

So far I have tried this `Grid`:

```
render() {
        const { multipleVideoSource } = this.state;
        return (
            multipleVideoSource !== null ?
            multipleVideoSource.map(src => (
                <div style={{ row: 'horizontal' }}>
                    <Grid container spacing={24}>
                        <Grid item xs={4}>
                            <Player key={src} height={500} fluid={false}>
                                <ControlBar autoHide={false} className="my-class" />
                                <BigPlayButton position="center" />
                                <HLSSource isVideoChild src={src} />
                            </Player>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </div>
            ))
            : "Only one video"
        );
    };
```

But with no luck. Any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using ReactJS? If so, please add that as a tag.

Comment: @Rojo I am, tag added.

Comment: The container needs to be outside the loop so that you have just one container (currently you have a separate container for each item).

Comment: @RyanCogswell That solves this, thank you a lot.

Comment: setting the container to flex and then set flex-direction: row should help I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
render() {
    const { multipleVideoSource } = this.state;

    const BunchOfPlayer = multipleVideoSource.map(src => (                           
          <Grid item xs={4}>
            <Player key={src} height={500} fluid={false}>
               <ControlBar autoHide={false} className="my-class" />
               <BigPlayButton position="center" />
               <HLSSource isVideoChild src={src} />
            </Player>
          </Grid>));

    return (
        multipleVideoSource !== null ?
          <Grid container spacing={24}>        
             {BunchOfPlayer}        
          </Grid>
        : "Only one video"
   );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If all you're using 'material-ui' for is to import a  component, then might I suggest using your own CSS which might be easy enough? If you already have control over the widths of the player elements & their container, you can simply add 'display:inline-block' on the div container:

`<div style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>`

This could cause issues with responsiveness, in which case you might want to check out some flex styles which give you more control. It's a little more CSS but will provide some more scalable, responsive solutions.

Basically you'd want to keep a container  that everything from your map() would return its elements into. This container  would have styles that look something like this:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div style={{ display:'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
      {renderPlayers()}
    </div>
  )
};

renderPlayers() {
        const { multipleVideoSource } = this.state;
        return (
            multipleVideoSource !== null ?
            multipleVideoSource.map(src => (
                <div> {/* maybe keep for flex-item style? Otherwise, not necessary */}
                  <Player key={src} height={500} fluid={false}>
                    <ControlBar autoHide={false} className="my-class" />
                    <BigPlayButton position="center" />
                    <HLSSource isVideoChild src={src} />
                  </Player>
                </div>
            ))
            : "Only one video"
        );
    };
```

Flex defaults to a 'flexDirection' of 'row' as well as a 'flexWrap' of 'nowrap', so you wouldn't have to set these for your horizontal Grid. (Unless you want it to wrap for smaller devices.)

You can also set styles for each individual child and play around with different Flexbox styles on sites like this https://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

I hope this helps!